# latest date field

Tags: sql, date, max

First off by means am I a programmer, I didn't any SQL courses and am self taught. All the data that i want pulls just fine, but I have a MAX set on a date field and it is still giving me all the dates from the table. I just want the latest. I am also have multiple joins so I am sure I don't have something set correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Pentaho as the writer

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     "RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN"."PAYER_PLAN_NAME",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."CLIENT_NUMBER",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."PROGRAM_ID",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P1_CODE",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P1_DESCRIPTION",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P2_CODE",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P2_DESCRIPTION",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P3_CODE",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P3_DESCRIPTION",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."PROGRAM",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."BEGIN_DATE",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."AGE",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."GENDER",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."MILITARY_SERVICES",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."MILITARY_STATUS",
     "RPT_SVCDOC_TOBACCO"."SMOKING_STATUS",
     "RPT_SVCDOC_REFERRAL"."REFER_COMMENT",
     "RPT_SVCDOC_REFERRAL"."REASON_FOR_REFERRAL",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN"."END_DATE",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."END_DATE",
     MAX("RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."EFFECTIVE_DATE") as max_date
FROM
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS" INNER JOIN "RPT_CLIENT" ON "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."CLIENT_ID" = "RPT_CLIENT"."CLIENT_ID"
     INNER JOIN "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG" ON "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."CLIENT_ID" = "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."CLIENT_ID"
     INNER JOIN "RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN" ON "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."CLIENT_ID" = "RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN"."CLIENT_ID"
     INNER JOIN "RPT_SVCDOC_TOBACCO" ON "RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN"."CLIENT_ID" = "RPT_SVCDOC_TOBACCO"."CLIENT_ID"
     INNER JOIN "RPT_SVCDOC_REFERRAL" ON "RPT_CLIENT"."CLIENT_NUMBER" = "RPT_SVCDOC_REFERRAL"."CLIENT_NUMBER"
WHERE
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."PROGRAM_ID" IN (1087)
     and "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."BEGIN_DATE" >= ${Begin_Date}
     and "RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN"."END_DATE" IS NULL

GROUP BY
    "RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN"."PAYER_PLAN_NAME",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."CLIENT_NUMBER",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."PROGRAM_ID",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P1_CODE",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P1_DESCRIPTION",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P2_CODE",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P2_DESCRIPTION",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P3_CODE",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."DSM5_P3_DESCRIPTION",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."PROGRAM",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."BEGIN_DATE",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."AGE",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."GENDER",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."MILITARY_SERVICES",
     "RPT_CLIENT"."MILITARY_STATUS",
     "RPT_SVCDOC_TOBACCO"."SMOKING_STATUS",
     "RPT_SVCDOC_REFERRAL"."REFER_COMMENT",
     "RPT_SVCDOC_REFERRAL"."REASON_FOR_REFERRAL",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_PLAN"."END_DATE",
     "RPT_CLIENT_PROGRAMS"."END_DATE",
     "RPT_CLIENT_DSM5_DIAG"."EFFECTIVE_DATE"
```

Hoping to get just the latest DMS-5 effective date, but still give me everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `max` on `EFFECTIVE_DATE` column, but it is also part of `group by`. As it is part of group by, each unique value of the column would appear on its own. Remove it from `group by` and it should work.